# Next.js fetch error on request to golang gin

Tags: go, next.js

I have this golang gin simple endpoint

```
...
    router.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "resp": "pong",
        })
    })
...
```

I can observe the response in my browser at http://127.0.0.1:8080/ping, and if I:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/ping
{"resp":"pong"}%
```

However, if I try to fetch with Next.js

```
...    
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/ping', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'no-cors',
    })

    console.log("response",response)
    const data = await response.json() // Errors here in the console with Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input 
...
```

and if I try to view the response in network tab of developer tools the response says

```
Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you configured your server for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)?

Comment: I followed [gin-contrib/cors example](https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors/blob/master/examples/example.go) and was able to fix this. Thanks @ju

Answer (score 1):

For reference https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors/blob/master/examples/example.go

Now, I udpated the go code with

```
...
    router.Use(cors.New(cors.Config{
        AllowAllOrigins: true,
    }))
...
   router.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "resp": "pong",
        })
    })
...
```

And then I udpated page.tsx (Next.js) removing `no-cors`

```
    const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/ping', {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors', // this was no-cors, updated to cors
    })
```

Now I can see the response from Next.js frontend as expected!